# put long bash command results into variable

Tags: bash

I'm using the below line in shell, it return results great, but how do I put the result into a variable? Please help:

```
SAVED="ffmpeg -i INPUT 2>&1 | grep "Duration"| cut -d ' ' -f 4 | sed s/,// | awk '{ split($1, A, ":"); split(A[3], B, "."); print 3600*A[1] + 60*A[2] + B[1] }'"

echo $SAVED | bash
```

Any kind of help I can get on this is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use backquotes or the special `$()` operator:

```
SAVED=`ffmpeg ...`
```

or

```
SAVED=$(ffmpeg ...)
```

Comment: `$( ... )` is vastly preferred over backquotes, which are still supported only for backwards compatibility.